# Rpi python GPIO PWM control L298 and PCA9685 motor HAT

Tags: rpi.gpio, python-3, dc-motor

I need to find out which GPIO pin on the raspberry pi will be connected to which module when I fit the Adeept Motor Hat v2.0 on the 40 GPIO pins. I am attaching the image and the schematic of the motor hat.

[image: Motor hat which fits on the 40 GPIO pins of Raspberry pi]

[Here](https://docdro.id/tyeUsts) is a link to the schematic.

PS. Since I am new to this I am not sure if this can be figured out or not.
Thanks!

Comment: A lot can be figured out by looking at the PDF.  The reset can be figured out by looking at the software.  You need to make your own list.

Comment: @joan Sir, I am afraid I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @Vaibhav, Ah, show me a photo of all the 2 pin connecting cables, and the two motors. You can also look at the schematic I just placed in the very bottom of my old answer.

Comment: I read the pdf user guide a second time and got confused. The manual says you should have two small motors. But did they give you only one big motor? Please let me have the user guide link, to make sure I am not reading the wrong manual. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: And you might like to read the two L298N references in my very first answer to your Mars Rover question.

Comment: @Vaibhav, Long time no see. Let me see see. I guess the impatient guy still doesn't know what is going on there. Now let me try to make things as simple as possible, but not simpler.  (1) I assume you know the following basic things about a toy motor, and please let me know otherwise: (a) A motor has a "coil", if current passes in one direction, it will turn, say clockwise. (b) If current passes in the opposite direction, it will turn counter clockwise. Now stare at my figure below for 3 minutes (me IQ97 need 5 minutes) and tell me if you can "figure out" anything. Happy thinking. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Answer***

Part 1

Part 2

/ to continue, ...

---

**Discussion, conclusion, and recommendation**

/ to continue, ...

---

***What next***

/ to continue, ...

---

***References***

(1) [Adafruit PCA9685 16-Channel PWM / Servo Controller Tutorial - Lady Ada](https://learn.adafruit.com/16-channel-pwm-servo-driver)

/ to continue, ...

---

***Appendices***

/ to continue, ...

---

***Photos***

/ to continue, ...

---

***Schematics***

/ to continue, ...

---

***Figures***

*Figure 1 - Basic principles of L298N Dual Bridge DC Motor Driver*
[image: l298 simple 1]

/ to continue, ...

---

*End of Answer*